# React Native Image is not displaying in android but it is displaying on iOS perfectly

Tags: android, typescript, react-native

I am struggling to display the image in android. I am using Image tag of react-native.
Some url is displaying in android and ios both, but specific url is not displaying in only android.

This image is not displaying.

```
import {  Image } from 'react-native'
... 
<Image 
 style={{
  width: 130,
  height: 130,
  resizeMode: 'contain',
 }}
 source={{uri: "https://www.cartier.com/variants/images/13452677152895292/img1/w828_tpadding12.jpg"}}
/>
```

but another url is displaying in android and ios both.

```
<Image 
 style={{
  width: 130,
  height: 130,
  resizeMode: 'contain',
 }}
 source={{uri: "https://content.thewosgroup.com/productimage/17311285/17311285_1.jpg?impolicy=zoom"}}
/>
```

I added permission to AndroidManifest.xml file.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

And also tried to add headers to source in Image tag.

```
<Image 
 style={{
  width: 130,
  height: 130,
  resizeMode: 'contain',
 }}
 source={{
    uri: "https://www.cartier.com/variants/images/13452677152895292/img1/w828_tpadding12.jpg",
    headers: {Accept: '*/*'}
 }}
/>
```

But it is not working.

How can I solve this?

Comment: try using react native fast image

Comment: Wow, perfect. it works. Thanks. btw the image resolution is not good in react-native-fast-image. Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: Image is blur in fastimage